# Extract and Crete new JSON string

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jackson

I have some spring MVC based APIs which produces JSON/ XML which represents API output.

```
{
    "data" : 
    {
  "users": [
            {
               "id": "001",
                "name: "abc1",
                "type": {
                      "id": "P",
                       "name": "Permanent"
                 }
            },
           {
                "id": "002",
                "name: "xyz",
                "type": {
                       "id": "C",
                       "name": "Contractor"
                 }
           }
     ]
    }
}
```

I'm passing a parameter with request as 
url?fields=users.id, users.type.id

users.type.id is a sub-node in users node.
users node is an array.

Now, what I want to do is to filter those only properties and create the response based upon fields passed in the request.

So the response to above filter condition should be same structure and will only contain wanted fields with values.
I'm trying to build a flat map with keys with a dot notation so I won't lose the track to filter, then I'll rebuild the JSON again. I feel this approach is just unreasonable because Jackson has the `.path` and `.with` API's to check existing path. But the real challenge is to extract and create a new JSON which matches the response JSON.

I'm looking for some ideas to achieve this. I don't want to try any third party libs btw. I know some libs are there. I want to prefer Jackson way to do this.

Feel free to add or comment if you have a further ideas.

Comment: you can use `@PathParam` instead of `@QueryParam`

Comment: @dehasi  It's not about providing the filter at URL level.. how can you filter json ..

Comment: are you looking for smth like `jsonpath`?

Comment: Similar to that but should get the same structure back. If I provide the filter condition = users.id i should get the structure same as above response containing only id with value and wrappers should be present like users and data.